# Vitis linking error "[CFGEN 83-2229] Failed to find single interface to reach all segments in {HP!, HP0, HP2}"

Tags: opencl, fpga, xilinx, hardware-acceleration, ros2

i am using the Kria Robotics Stack with Vitis 2022.1 to accelerate my ROS2 nodes on the KR260.
Using OpenCL C Kernels, i am trying to connect the kernel ports to AXI-Interfaces to access global memory in parallel.

For example i have three kernel arguments 'x', 'w' and 'randNum'.
In my kv260.cfg file i try to tell the vivado linker, that he should connect these three arguments to different port. So i do:

```
[connectivity]
sp=kernel_1.x:HP!
sp=kernel_1.w:HP0
sp=kernel_1.randNum:HP2
```

However, if i try to synthesize the kernel, i get following error message from the linker:

```
[CFGEN 83- 2229] Failed to find single interface to reach all segments in {HP!, HP0, HP2}
```

I cannot not find any information about this error message and i have no clue, why i get such an error message.

I hope somebody can help me with this issue or can share a link, where the error Vitis Compiler/Linker error codes are documented.

Thanks!!

PS: Don't be confused about the HP! tag. I think it is a typo from the developers of the platform. If i execute the platforminfo command on the .xpfm file i get:

```
=====================================
Memory Information:
=====================================
Bus SP Tag: HP!
Bus SP Tag: HP0
Bus SP Tag: HP2
Bus SP Tag: HP3
Bus SP Tag: HPC0
Bus SP Tag: HPC1
```

I have also tried it with C/C++-Kernel and it worked. I'm not sure, what's the problem with OpenCL C Kernels.